# How do I convert my Website into Android App

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

I made a website, and now I want to convert it into an App.

I have **literally no knowledge** of Java or Android apps. I google'ed about it but, I am still confused from where should I start?

I am not asking, anyone to code for me. I just want to know, the steps, by which I can achieve my goal. From where should I start?

Please tell me, what are the steps. Maybe, I am searching with wrong keywords on Google.

And is there any open source or free project, that can help me do it?

Comment: You can go for hybrid app (PhoneGap,ionic etc)

Comment: If you've done your site in AngularJS or Angular, you could migrate to ionic,

Comment: HTML, CSS, JS, PHP...Yeah, i want hybrid app.

Answer (score 5):

**1. The Basic Usage**

Integrating a WebView in your app won’t take more than two steps. First you need to include the WebView element in your xml layout.

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Second you have load the specific url in webview from your activity. The below loads google’s homepage into web view.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("YOUR WEBSITE LINK HERE");
```

Even though loading a simple url seems very easy, customizing the WebView needs thorough knowledge over WebView and the methods it is providing. We’ll start with basic methods WebView is providing and later on we’ll build a simple browser activity which acts as in-app browser that provides backward, forward and bookmark options. We’ll learn one by one by starting a simple project in Android Studio.

**2. Creating New Project**

1. Create a new project in Android Studio from File ⇒ New Project by filling the required details.
2. As we need to make network requests, we need to add INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.webview" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3. Open build.gradle and add Glide library support. This is required to load the image in CollapsingToolbar. This step is optional, but I suggest you follow it for this article.

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    // glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

4. Open the layout files your main activity (activity_main.xml and content_main.xml) and the WebView element. Along with this, I am also adding CoordinatorLayout, Toolbar and a ProgressBar which will be shown while the webpage is being loaded.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

5. Now open the MainActivity.java and modify the code as below. Here initCollapsingToolbar() method is completely unrelated to WebView, but it is to provide collapsing effect when webpage is scrolled up. The Glide method is used to display the header image in toolbar.

```
    package info.androidhive.webview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String postUrl = "http://api.androidhive.info/webview/index.html";
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageView imgHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        imgHeader = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);

        // initializing toolbar
        initCollapsingToolbar();

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(postUrl);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * Initializing collapsing toolbar
     * Will show and hide the toolbar txtPostTitle on scroll
     */
    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the txtPostTitle when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Web View");
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });

        // loading toolbar header image
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://api.androidhive.info/webview/nougat.jpg")
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgHeader);
    }
}
```

For rest of the code [WEBVIEW EXAMPLE HERE](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/12/android-working-with-webview-building-a-simple-in-app-browser/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Webview to show your Website in Android App

Comment: I think OP should try this answer once. It just takes some 10 to 15 mins to implement and check this process.

Comment: Yeah, but that's my question, how to implement it? I will try to use Phonegap, and inform you, if i face any problem, thanks :)